# How can I run js automatic without calling it(as a function)?

Tags: javascript

I want to run `window.alert("hi")` every time I load a specific URL.

For example: The page will say "hi" automatic without calling a javascript function.

Comment: What do you mean "without injecting it"?

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a function & call it on-load(document/window) or just put the js within script tag on the page(it would work as soon as that part is loaded).

Example using `onload` (this alerts "Page is loaded" as soon as the `body` loads):

```html
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Page is loaded");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Example (by adding `script` between the HTML):

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    alert("Page is loaded");
  </script>

  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Using `window.onload`(THis loads as soon as the window is done loading) :

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    window.onload = function(e) {
      alert("Hello window is loaded");
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Reference : [window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)